# Create video from string data using PHP

Tags: php, ios

I am creating web services in php for iOS. The web service is to upload image and video from iOS front end to server.

I have successfully uploaded image to server using `imagecreatefromstring($img_string)`.

How to convert the string data to video in similar manner?

Is there any function for the same?

Comment: if you send it to php in binary , you need use simple function file_put_content()

Comment: Are you got an answer for that question?